# Multiple cameras using a single skybox with same perspective

Tags: unity, camera, skybox

I am using the enviro package for weather and to have a moving sun in the background. I'm building an installation with 3 screens and I want to have the sun track across the screens. However what I end up with is 3 separate skyboxes and 3 suns, one on each screen.

Is there a way I can have the cameras share a single skybox?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you've set up your scene?

Comment: @DMGregory I've added a picture of our current setup (two screens)

Comment: That helps too, but what I'm looking for is the setup of your game scene inside the Unity editor.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the camera directions on each screen to match the relative display locations and synchronize everything else between the screens.

That way you will with a setup that looks like 3 different cameras looking at the same skybox.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are in the Editor, and you have opened 3 Game tabs, each game tab is a separate game render. You need to either move ONE game tab out from the main view and resize stretch it to fit all 3 screens at the same time, or build program and launch it(once) in one window.